Horror movie, man with hole in abdomen starts to grow tentacles
I can only remember a scene and there are two guys in a room one of them has a big hole in his abdomen. The other guy shoves something inside the hole. The first guy starts to grow what look like tentacles around his arm and body. I've been looking for this film for ages. It might have won some international obscure awards but I'm not sure.

When did you see this?  Any details can be used to rule out more recent movies.

I think the scene you are describing is a key scene in the movie Videodrome with James Woods, Debby Harry, and Les CarlsonFrom IMDB:Under Convex's influence he produces a pulsating VHS tape and Renn's stomach-slit opens to receive his program. Convex (Les Carlson) orders Renn (James Woods) to: "kill your partners and give me Channel 83." Renn pulls his gun back from the slit and black metal tendrils extend into his hand.
Renn goes back to Channel 83 station and shoots both Moses and Raphael in the Channel 8 boardroom, his gun/hand now a single organic fusion.The Cronenberg film is about Woods, who hijacks an illicit cable feed from Japan, investigating and finding it is a form of hallucinagenic mind control. Very cool movie with really disgustingly satisfying video effects for the early 80s.
